# Elements of order $50$ of $Z_{25}*Z_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I have to find the elements of order $50$ from $Z_{25}*Z_{10}$.
I know how to find elements of order $k$ from any $Z_n$ but I'm not that sure how to go about doing when there is a $Z_n * Z_m$ , can you please give me a hint/solve + explanation on how to do this ?

Thank you.

What I know : $O_{G_{1}*G_{2}}((x_1,x_2)) = lcm[O_{G_1}(x_1), O_{G_2}(x_2)]$

But I don't know how to apply that on the problem above.

Comment: find an element of order two and an element of order $25$

Comment: because $50 = 2 * 25$ ?

Comment: Just use your “What I know”. If you’re having trouble with this, try $\Bbb Z_9*\Bbb Z_{10}$ and find en element of order $18$. Use paper, write things down, enumerated the elements of the groups, do anything that works!

Comment: can you please explain the steps in an answer ? I would really appreciate it, I need to understand these types of problems for an exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ have order $1, 5$, or $25$.  Elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ have order $1, 2, 5$, or $10$.  You'll have to find elements  $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}_{25}\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ so that the least common multiple of the orders of $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ respectively is $50$.

Comment: Using $O_{Z_{25}*Z_{10}}((a,b)) = [O_{Z_{25}}(a), O_{Z_{10}}(b)] = [3, 4] = 12$ and how do I find $(a,b)$ so that the $lcm(a,b)$ is $50$ ? Can you please give a few examples of $(a,b)$, maybe I can understand from those examples.

Comment: You don't want the LCM of $a$ and $b$ to be $50$, but rather the LCM of their orders.  For instance $(1, 1)$ has order LCM$(25,10)=50$.  $(1,2)$ has order $25$.  $(7, 5)$ has order $50$.

Comment: but the order of $7$ in $Z_{25}$ is $25$ and the order of $5$ in $Z_{10}$ is $5$ which means $lcm(25,5) = 25$ not $50$, so how does the order of $(7,5)$ equal to $50$ ?

Comment: @southpaw93 Actually the order of $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is $2$.

Comment: ohhh damn, yeah, that's true, now I see, so $lcm(25,2) = 50$ that means $(7,5) = 50$, amazing, now I understand, thank you so much.

Comment: quick question: now I have to find the $(a,b)$ pairs of $a$ order $5$ in $Z_{25}$ and $b$ order $10$ in $Z_{10}$, then $(a,b)$ pairs of $a$ order $25$ in $Z_{25}$ and $b$ order $2$ in $Z_{10}$ and form pairs of that ?

Comment: Order 5, order 10 pairs will give you order 10 in the product.

Comment: oh, so just order 25 with order 2 and order 25 with order 10, right ?

Comment: all order $25$ elements of $Z_{25}$ are ${1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24}$ and all order $2$ elements of $Z_{10}$ are ${2,4,6,8}$, so we form pairs of these ?